# PHP - Populating aggregated objects - Best Practise

Tags: php, oop, orm, data-mapping

I have a **Product** object which also aggregates a few "arrays of objects" **Property, Category, Color, Size** etc.
now I have database which contains tables against each object ...  ***products, properties, categories, colors, sizes*** etc.
Now my query to retrieve list of products has 7-8 joins as my database has a few other tables which contains many to many relationships for the products and its related entities.

All is fine. Now problem comes when I retrieve data from PDO and need to populate my product along-with all of its aggregated objects. 
I need to make many nested loops to fill my array of Product objects which is quite a cumbersome   activity and also does not seem to be a good programming practise (intuitively).

**I don't want to use any ORM as in my opinion ORMs are very inefficient for these number of joins.**

*What is the best practise to deal with this kind of situation.*

Thank you very much for your time.

**Edit: (based on  KIKO Software comments)**

Where clause of most of my product retrieval queries, would contain conditions, related to its aggregated entities, and as I wrote earlier I have some many to many relations as well. So It means that I am already using database resources "even" if I go for lazy-loading. So, In that case eager-loading would be better choice if I load a subset of my result? If so, again my original question stays same; can I not escape from too many nested loops to load aggregated objects?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should have get and set methods in your product object for things like proterties, catagories, color and size. What I normally do is only retrieve these objects when they are actually needed. So only when you use a get routine. This way you can create a new product object quite quickly, because it is not slowed down by retrieving all the arrays, especially when you're not even using them.

As you pointed out in your comment, this is call *lazy-loading*: You only retrieve what is required.

I can see no good reason for *eager-loading* database data. In other words: load everything as soon as possible. The only reason could be if you can do it faster than *lazy-loading* the data, and you know you probably need all the data.

I my opinion there's not much you can do in PDO to speed up the retrieval of several rows from different tables (apart from the normal database optimazations). `fetchAll()` might be slightly faster than `fetch()`, but this will be marginal. So the best strategy remains *lazy-loading*.

There are however several ways you can implement *lazy-loading*. Whenever a call to a get method is made, you could only retrieve the requested row, or you could retrieve all the needed rows from the associated tablet in one go. The first method is more efficient when there are a lot of rows to be retrieved and you probably need only a few of them. The second method is the best choice when there are not that many rows to be retrieved and you probably need most of them anyway.

So the specific method used depends on your needs, but in all cases *lazy-loading* is probably the best practice.

Comment: Thank you for a solution, I can look into it to see if it fits according to the needs. Is there any other workaround if I need eager-loading?
Secondly, What normally is the cause of the retrieval process to be slowed down: Retrieving data from the database or looping through each record to populate objects? (if the database table sizes are not too large)

Comment: Your first question should really be answered in a answer, not in a comment. As to your second question: Database access slows things down far more than anything you do to store the retrieved data in a php object. So whenever you do not need to access the database, you should not do so. Database access can be speeded up by a lot of factors, such as: location of the server, speed of the server, indexing, proper data normalization, and many more. Just using joins doesn't really help all that much. But whenever in doubt measure it!

Comment: I have edited my original question based on your comments. Thanks for giving me a direction.